# How to use a bit to store a config in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, bitmask

For example, to store config1-8 to config

```
var config1 = false
var config2 = false
var config3 = false
var config4 = false
var config5 = false
var config6 = false
var config7 = false
var config8 = false
var config = 0
```

if config is

```
var config1 = false
var config2 = false
var config3 = false
var config4 = false
var config5 = false
var config6 = false
var config7 = false
var config8 = true
```

then config is 1

if config is

```
var config1 = false
var config2 = false
var config3 = false
var config4 = false
var config5 = false
var config6 = false
var config7 = true
var config8 = false
```

then config is 2

if config is

```
var config1 = false
var config2 = false
var config3 = false
var config4 = false
var config5 = false
var config6 = false
var config7 = true
var config8 = true
```

then config is 3

And then how to check each config value in the integer? if config is 3, how to know config 7 and 8 is true?

Comment: You can do it this way, but you'd generally be much better off using an enum and an EnumSet rather than managing this yourself.

Comment: I don't understand how to use enum to apply to this case

Comment: do you mean, I should not use bit, I should use enum?

Comment: Use an enum for each of the configurations you want, and an EnumSet to store which are present and which are not.

Comment: @LouisWasserman can you show me the Kotlin API documentation for EnumSet?

Comment: Check my answer for an idiomatic example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To read and write booleans as int just use binary masks:

```
var config1 = true
var config2 = true
var config3 = false
var config4 = false
var config5 = false
var config6 = true
var config7 = true
var config8 = false


fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    var config = 0
    if(config1){ config = config or 0b10000000}
    if(config2){ config = config or 0b1000000}
    if(config3){ config = config or 0b100000}
    if(config4){ config = config or 0b10000}
    if(config5){ config = config or 0b1000}
    if(config6){ config = config or 0b100}
    if(config7){ config = config or 0b10}
    if(config8){ config = config or 0b1}

    println(config and 0b10000000 > 0)
    println(config and 0b1000000 > 0)
    println(config and 0b100000 > 0)
    println(config and 0b10000 > 0)
    println(config and 0b1000 > 0)
    println(config and 0b100 > 0)
    println(config and 0b10 > 0)
    println(config and 0b1 > 0)
}
```

The output will be

```
true
true
false
false
false
true
true
false
```

Comment: This is needlessly complicated. OP should use the built-in `EnumSet` instead.

Comment: It is direct answer to the question. I wonder why have you downvoted. Of course there are better ways to do that.

Comment: I have missed something in my question, now I can set a config on and check a config true false, how to set a config to off?

Answer (score 2):

For bit calculations, you'd define the bits manually as a power of 2:

```
const val CONFIG8 = 1
const val CONFIG7 = 2
const val CONFIG6 = 4
...
```

Then you can set a config with the `or` operator:

```
config = 0
config = config or CONFIG8 // = 1
config = config or CONFIG7 // = 3
```

To read the which config is set you'd use the `and` operator

```
config and CONFIG8 != 0 // true if 1 or 3 ...
config and CONFIG7 != 0 // true if 2 or 3 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a **bitvector** and Java (and by extension Kotlin) has a built-in solution for this problem, the `EnumSet`. Example:

```
object Demo {

    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {


        val configs: EnumSet<Config> = EnumSet.of(ONE, THREE, FIVE)


        println(configs.joinToString())
        // ONE, THREE, FIVE

    }

    enum class Config {
        ONE,
        TWO,
        THREE,
        FOUR,
        FIVE
    }

}
```

An `EnumSet` will use bit vectors internally but you don't need to mess with it manually.

The relevant parts from the docs:

> A specialized Set implementation for use with enum types. All of the elements in an enum set must come from a single enum type that is specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the set is created. Enum sets are represented internally as bit vectors. This representation is extremely compact and efficient. The space and time performance of this class should be good enough to allow its use as a high-quality, typesafe alternative to traditional int-based "bit flags." Even bulk operations (such as containsAll and retainAll) should run very quickly if their argument is also an enum set.

Comment: EnumSet is part of the Java API. The OP didn't specify Kotlin/JVM, only Kotlin. So EnumSet is not available for all flavours of Kotlin. For this reason, I wish I could give you half a + but I've had to round it up to a +1.